# SQL: Get a list and use all items in the output for another query

Tags: sql, database, wordpress

I use several SQL queries for completing a table, but i think it's also possible to get it with only one query. Here is the structure:

There is the table 'wp_postmeta'; including id, post_id, meta_key and meta_value as the columns. In that table, rows with meta_key = x has user ID values in the meta_value part. I want to get the post_id value with a given meta_key and user id value (which is in meta_value part) and use that post_id to get certain meta_values with given meta_keys. Here is an example. Let's say that User ID is 9:

SELECT CONCAT((SELECT 'meta_value' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = y AND 'post_id' = (SELECT 'post_id' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = x AND 'meta_value' = 9)),(SELECT 'meta_value' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = z AND 'post_id' = (SELECT 'post_id' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = x AND 'meta_value' = 9)),(SELECT 'meta_value' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = w AND 'post_id' = (SELECT 'post_id' FROM 'wp_postmeta' WHERE 'meta_key' = x AND 'meta_value' = 9)))

With that query, I have concatenated the meta values for given meta keys, belonging to a post related to a given user ID. (y,z,w). The issue is that I can get what I want correctly for a given User ID, but I want to give a list of User ID's and get their corresponding concatenated results. How can I achieve that? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want and your existing query.  And provide a database tag.

Comment: I have added my attempt for single User ID and gave more detail about the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be describing something like this (using MySQL syntax):

```
select p.*, group_concat(pm.metavalue) as metavalues
from wp_posts p left join
     wp_postmeta pm
     on pm.post_id =  p.post_id
where p.user_id in ( . . . )
group by p.user_id;
```